# Spring boot thymeleaf and datatables delete data

Tags: spring-boot, datatables, thymeleaf

i'm learning spring boot with datatables. and now im success show data from MySQL to jquery datatables. and now im create CRUD, but my problem on this learning is delete data.

i'm understand with only table bootstrap create CRUD without datatables :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Product Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="product : ${products}">
            <td th:text="${product.id}"><a href="/product/${product.id}">Id</a></td>
            <td th:text="${product.productId}">Product Id</td>
            <td th:text="${product.name}">descirption</td>
            <td th:text="${product.price}">price</td>
            <td><a th:href="${'/product/delete/' + product.id}">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

easy only declare local variable thymeleaf on my html.

how delete data from datatables with confirmation dialog ?

this my code datatables :

```
$(document).ready (function() {
var table = $('#productsTable').DataTable({
    "sAjaxSource": "/api/products",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "",
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    "columns": [
        { "mData": "id"},
        { "mData": "name" },
        { "mData": "price" },
        { "mData": "productId" },
        { "mData": "version" },
        {
            data: null,
            defaultContent: '<a href="" class="remove">Delete</a>',
            orderable: false
        }
    ]
});


$('#btnDelete').on( 'click', 'a.remove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        editor.remove( $(this).closest('tr'), {
            title: 'Delete Product',
            message: 'Are you sure you wish to delete this data ?',
            buttons: 'Delete'
        } );
    } );

});
```

products.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Latihan Spring Boot</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/product.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
              href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 align="center">Products Table</h1>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</a></p>
            <table id="productsTable" class="display">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Product ID</th>
                        <th>Version</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery [`confirm()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp).

Update your code like so

```
$('#btnDelete').on( 'click', 'a.remove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!confirm("Sure you want to delete!")){
            return false;
        }
        editor.remove( $(this).closest('tr'), {
            title: 'Delete Product',
            message: 'Are you sure you wish to delete this data ?',
            buttons: 'Delete'
        } );
    } );

});
```

Comment: That is not what I mean. i mean, how to delete data from datatables like my code without datatables only thymeleaf (my top code) with confirm dialog :D. at line here im confused 'defaultContent: '<a href="" class="remove">Delete</a>''

Comment: I dont think i quite understand you. But if you just want to do the same with thymleaf. You can create a delete function and trigger it from your Thymleaf generated HTML lists.

Comment: if without datatables im understad, but using datatables im not understad. here im confused `defaultContent: '<a href="" class="remove">Delete</a>'`. how to delete code like this to get by id `<a th:href="${'/product/delete/' + product.id}">Delete</a>`